# SMBIOS - Invalid structure table address?

Tags: dos, x86-16, bios, firmware

I'm currently working on an old MS-DOS application, which uses DMI to identify the hardware. It worked fine in the past, but it seems to provide invalid data on newer systems (e.g. Skylake). As stated in the spec, we are scanning 0xF0000-0xFFFFF for the "*SM*" anchor string, this is still working as expected.

But now it seems that the data located at the "Structure table adress" (stored at offset 0x18h in the) are invalid (see dumps below). Tools like dmidecoe deliver correct information (however, it uses GetSystemFirmwareTable() on Windows). What I am doing wrong here?

**EDIT (clarify situation)**

On an older system I get expected data (dump is done in FreeDOS' debug98 utility) - following come from an IvyBridge system (3rd gen.):

```
-d F000:04C0
F000:04C0  5F 53 4D 5F 03 1F 02 07-77 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   _SM_....w.......
F000:04D0  5F 44 4D 49 5F E0 6E 04-10 BA 0E 00 17 00 27 00   _DMI_.n.......'.
F000:04E0  1E 66 60 68 00 F0 1F B8-90 D0 83 C0 0F 24 F0 A3   .f`h.........$..
F000:04F0  1D 03 B9 00 E0 2B C8 79-02 33 C9 89 0E 1F 03 33   .....+.y.3.....3
F000:0500  C0 66 2E 8B 1E 63 00 66-83 FB 00 74 0B 66 81 FB   .f...c.f...t.f..
F000:0510  00 00 0E 00 72 02 8B C3-A3 19 03 F7 D0 A3 1B 03   ....r...........
F000:0520  66 61 1F C3 00 1E 50 68-00 F0 1F 0B DB 74 28 F7   fa....Ph.....t(.
F000:0530  C3 80 00 74 1C 2E 80 3E-24 05 00 75 43 83 F9 3E   ...t...>$..uC..>
-d E000:BA10
E000:BA10  00 18 00 00 01 02 00 F0-03 7F 80 98 89 3F 01 00   .............?..
E000:BA20  00 00 03 0D 04 06 FF FF-41 6D 65 72 69 63 61 6E   ........American
E000:BA30  20 4D 65 67 61 74 72 65-6E 64 73 20 49 6E 63 2E    Megatrends Inc.
E000:BA40  00 42 51 37 37 52 31 31-31 00 30 37 2F 30 35 2F   .BQ77R111.07/05/
E000:BA50  32 30 31 33 00 00 01 1B-01 00 01 02 03 04 00 00   2013............
E000:BA60  01 26 60 24 00 05 00 06-00 07 00 08 00 09 06 05   .&`$............
E000:BA70  06 20 00 20 00 20 00 30-30 30 30 30 31 32 36 36   . . . .000001266
E000:BA80  30 32 34 00 20 00 20 00-00 02 0F 02 00 01 02 03   024. . .........
```

Newer systems - in this case a Skylake based one (6th gen.) data are different. In the adress the *SMI* structure points to i do not get the expected data (I expcted  to see the BIOS strings, but they are not there):

```
-d f000:05e0
F000:05E0  5F 53 4D 5F F3 1F 03 00-8C 01 00 00 00 00 00 00   _SM_............
F000:05F0  5F 44 4D 49 5F 15 CE 07-00 90 1D 87 1A 00 30 00   _DMI_.........0.
F000:0600  5F 53 4D 33 5F 4A 18 03-00 00 01 00 CE 07 00 00   _SM3_J..........
F000:0610  00 90 1D 87 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
F000:0620  1E 66 60 68 00 F0 1F B8-00 C6 83 C0 0F 24 F0 A3   .f`h.........$..
F000:0630  8E 03 B9 00 E0 2B C8 79-02 33 C9 89 0E 90 03 33   .....+.y.3.....3
F000:0640  C0 66 2E 8B 1E 63 00 66-83 FB 00 74 0B 66 81 FB   .f...c.f...t.f..
F000:0650  00 00 0E 00 72 02 8B C3-A3 8A 03 F7 D0 A3 8C 03   ....r...........
-d 871d:9000
871D:9000  76 06 D1 E9 73 08 8A 05-A4 88 44 FF 74 08 8B 05   v...s.....D.t...
871D:9010  A5 89 44 FE E2 F8 5F 5E-5D C2 04 00 55 8B EC 4C   ..D..._^]...U..L
871D:9020  4C 56 57 83 7E 04 02 73-2D 83 7E 04 02 74 03 E9   LVW.~..s-.~..t..
871D:9030  18 01 8B 46 06 03 06 AC-10 8B F8 50 FF 76 06 FF   ...F.......P.v..
871D:9040  16 AE 10 59 59 0B C0 7F-03 E9 FE 00 FF 76 06 57   ...YY........v.W
871D:9050  E8 9D FF E9 F4 00 8B 46-04 48 F7 2E AC 10 8B 56   .......F.H.....V
871D:9060  06 03 D0 8B FA 8B 46 04-D1 E8 F7 2E AC 10 8B 56   ......F........V
871D:9070  06 03 D0 8B F2 57 56 FF-16 AE 10 59 59 0B C0 7E   .....WV....YY..~
```

Comment: The total of the bytes in the table has a lower value of 00 so that suggests it is valid. The Structure Table Address in the header is a 32-bit physical address (linear) and it is at `0x871d9000`. You are dumping (With DOS debug?) a segment:offset address `871d:9000` which is physical address (0x871d<<4)+0x9000=`0x901D0` . On systems that worked, what was the Structure Table Address for those?

Comment: Segmented address and 32-bit physical addresses are not the same thing. If this is MS-DOS is your program going into unreal mode or protected mode to read the structure table from memory above 1MiB?

Comment: Given that your table is at `0x871d9000` and that address falls on an odd numbered megabyte boundary I hope that the [A20 line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A20_line) is enabled or you won't be reading from the right memory location.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, Michael. I have to investigate your inputs and will come back to this a.s.a.p. The dump is done under FreeDOS - which gave me expected results in the past. It seems to be different on newer systems - in actual case a system with Skylake based CPU.

Comment: Would be curious to see added to your question the same kind of dumps but on an older system that worked. It may have worked by luck/coincidence previously. The MS-DOS program you are using - do you have source code for it or was it written by someone else and you just have an EXE? –

Comment: Yes, I have the code, it was written several years ago by myself using an old Borland C IDE (please do not ask why I did it this way). I am sure that I didn't take care about the A20 line or protected mode. Sounds like I have to rework the entire code so that I am able to address physical memory adresses??

Comment: Aha. So when it worked you had an address like: `10 BA 0E 00`. I can only imagine that when you processed this address your code swapped (fudged) the two bytes  `0e 00` so it became segment  0x0e00. You would have had to _fix_ this value before using it. Your code only worked by luck because it just so happened after loading and converting the value to segment:offset addressing you got `0xe000:0xba10` . (0xe000<<4)+0xba10=0x0eba10 (physical address).By luck that physical address happened to equal the real physical address stored in memory all along.

Comment: Reversing all the bytes (big endian) should have always yielded `10 BA 0E 00` or 0x000eba10`. I can only say that whatever your code was that incorrectly swapped the bytes in the segment to get an address should never have worked but it did out of luck. Up until now all the addresses were below 1MiB as well, but now they are above 1MiB. They always could have been above 1MiB but they weren't until recently with hardware. The hardware isn't at fault, how you have been interpreting the addresses and using them has been.

Comment: You will need to either get into unreal mode or protected mode because you will need to read from memory addresses that may be above 1MiB. In the new case your data structure is at 0x871D9000.  Roll your own code (enter protected mode and do code or enter unreal mode). IN the old days you could write programs that used DOS extenders (usually DPMI based) that allowed DOS code to run in protected mode. Watcom C use to have the option of DOS4GW support. These days though if I was tasked with writing C/C++ code I'd use [DJGPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DJGPP)

Comment: DJGPP is a version of C/C++ (based on GCC) that generates 32-bit code but the code runs in protected mode through a DPMI based DOS extender. You can write code that can access memory above 1MiB very easily. Despite being in protected mode it has a mechanism to handle calls to 16-bit real mode DOS/BIOS  interrupts.

Comment: One other option is to use [Int 15h/ah=87h System - Copy extended memory](http://ftp.mpoli.fi/pub/unpacked/software/texts/computer/inter58a.zip/interrup.c) to copy memory above 1MiB to memory below 1MiB. I don't know anything about your DOS environment or whether you are using a memory manager that already has the machine in protected mode or not etc. so it is difficult to say what options are available to you.

Comment: There are still uses for old compilers if you need to write for certain enviornments. I'd be curious what version of Borland C are you using. What version? Was it one with an IDE, are you creating q6-bit Windows app? 16-bit DOS application? 32-bit DOS application? 32-bit Windows application? If you are creating 16-bit DOS applications what memory model small, tiny, compact, medium, large?

Comment: I ask these questions as I may be able to help but as it is the info given is too broad. It would help to know the information requested as it would help narrow down to a more specific solution.

Comment: Just to answer your questions: The application was coded/compiled using Borland Turbo C++ 3.0 (has IDE). Since I didn't thought much about compiler options etc. I assume that it will create 16bit-DOS applications as per default. Looking into compuler options I can see that "Large" memory model is used - I can't remember that this was set by mine, therefore I think it's an default setting too.

Comment: Howdy Willy, I had time yesterday and today to look at a possible solution that can work with 16-bit Turbo-C on a 386+ processor. I do have functioning code that uses Unreal mode to access memory above the 1MiB area. Before I look at answering with code an a question (I still have major clean up to do) I need to know what happens when you run http://vps2.capp-sysware.com/so/downloads/smbios.exe . Does it exit with an error? If so which One. If it mentions being in protected mode already (v8086) you will have to deactivate your expanded memory manager. What brand/version of DOS do you use?

Comment: If it works the output should scroll, but you can use the command line `smbios.exe | more` to page through the output. If it has proper memory access it should show the DMI BIOS Info Structure (version, vendor name, build date). All the other types are ignored and printed as `other`. I only coded the BIOS Info Type 0 for proof of concept.

Comment: I forgot to ask. You said you are using Turbo-C/C++. Do you use `.C` file or `.CPP` files? I'm curious to know which you are using (C or C++) for your project.

Answer (score 1):

Your SMBIOS structures are located at physical address `0x871d9000` (as seen from offset f000:0610, or offset x10 from the '`_SM3_`' anchor string), as Michael Petch points out.

This is a minor point but could be important depending on how your software is constructed.  Keep in mind this is a SMBIOS 3.0 conforming structure (per the "`_SM3_`" anchor string) and that the structure table address can be on **any** 64-bit address.  To ensure your software works in all systems, you should use the `_SM3_` structure table address when present and enable your software to read any 64-bit physical address using big-real mode or other mechanism.  When the `_SM3_` structure is not present, then revert back to your old software flow.

As for why you are just now seeing this, is this the first time you have encountered a data structure that is above 1MB physical address?

Comment: Yes - this is the first time a runt into this troubles. I agree that have to look for "_SM3_"-structure in before. However, I fear that I have no idea how to access such addresses from within my very old MS-DOS-based C-program. If possible - do you know some good examples?

Comment: Look into using Unreal mode (or big-real mode as we used to call it).  Here is a link with sample code [link](https://wiki.osdev.org/Unreal_Mode).  Give the code at the link a try.  Reply back if you have problems.

Comment: OK, I'm out. I have basic understanding of assembly code, but I don't think that I will get this working. However, have much thanks for your inputs.